# ChangeDetector не запускается

Tags: angular

```
<div class="fields-container" *ngIf="props">
    <nav>
        <div class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <a (click)="changeTab(1)" class="nav-link cursor-pointer" [ngClass]="{'active': activeTab == 1}" data-toggle="tab"
                role="tab">Basic</a>
            <a (click)="changeTab(2)" class="nav-link cursor-pointer" [ngClass]="{'active': activeTab == 2}" data-toggle="tab"
                role="tab">Advanced</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>

  changeTab(tab) {
    this.activeTab = tab;
    // this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
```

Первый раз, когда props становиться true, все работает
Второй раз, при клике на кнопку, cdr уже не вызывается сам, необходимо вызывать вручную через this.cdr.detectChanges().

Кода мало, сказать точную причину сложно, но у вас такое было, что ломался запуск changeDetector-а?
По идеи, это происходит потому, что событие (click) больше не вызывает detectChanges автоматически, то есть зона потеряна?

Если добавлю

```
interval(1000).subscribe(r => {
  this.testValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
})
```

в конструктор, то changeDetector запускается каждую секунду, и не "ломается", так, как ломается на событиях.

Comment: Добавьте больше кода, не совсем понятно, какая у вас стратегия обнаружения изменений, как вы вызываетеchangeDetection и т.д.

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin Default, но проблема не в стратегии, и не в вызове cdr (если я вызываю, то все работает). Проблема в  том, что Angular не запускает changeDetector после клика. Вопрос можно перефразировать так: 
"как сделать., чтобы при клике на кнопку, не запускался changeDetector?". Вот это и происходит у меня (сама функция вызывается, но changeDetector не запускается.

Comment: Возможно, где-то выше по дереву стоит компонент с OnPush стратегией и это ломает changeDetection

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin ладно, я уже нашел кажется причину
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61712865/angular-click-event-handler-not-triggering-change-detection